# How to disable the "this cable or accessory is not certified" message on iPhone?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone, charging, power

The message "this cable or accessory is not certified and may not work reliably with this iPhone" pops up whenever I use a 3rd party USB cable for it. It's really annoying, because then I'd have to unplug it, then plug it in again for it to start charging (the pop up message prevents phone from getting charged).

Is there some way to disable it? I'm fine with jailbreak tweaks as my iPhone 5 is jailbroken. I very highly doubt it's actually anything to do with the cable because I've been using it for a year now and no problems whatsoever, it's obviously just Apple's way of tricking users to buy their completely overpriced accessories by throwing in this annoyance.

Comment: My bet is the voltage or current provided is outside the acceptable range.  After all how else could it be detected?

Comment: It's just a USB cable, not a power source. I plug it to my computer or use the original Apple charging block when plugged to the wall.

Answer (score 4):

So iPhone 5s use a Lightning cable rather than the old school dock connector.

Lightning cables actually have an authentication chip in them, hence the message.

[There's a jailbreak tweak out there](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2014/01/cydia-tweak-enable-compatibility-with-unauthorized-lightning-cables) that may be worth checking out, but it's quite old and may not have been updated.

Your best bet would be to just get a new cable. [Certified cables can be had for $8 on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010S9N6OO), and you don't run any risks of having dodgy cable damage your phone.

It's not just Apple protecting their profits, either. [Certification actually means standards were followed.](http://www.cnet.com/news/why-im-done-buying-cheap-lightning-cables/)